# Changing fopen() mode midway through?

Tags: php, file, fopen

I this piece of code:

```
$file = fopen($path, 'r+');
flock($file, LOCK_EX);
// reading the file into an array and doing some stuff to it
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
  {
  fwrite($file, $array[$i]);
  }
flock($file, LOCK_UN);
fclose($file);
```

Basically what I want to do is: open a file > lock it > read it > do some stuff > **clear the file** > write to file > unlock it > close it.

The problem is the clearing part. I know I could do it with `fopen($file, 'w+')` but then reading would be a problem. Maybe I can change the `mode` somehow?

Any help would be appreciated, Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the pointer to 0 using `fseek` you can then run `ftruncate` like so:

```
// reading the file into an array and doing some stuff to it

//1
fseek($handle,0); //Set the pointer to the first byte

//2
ftruncate($handle,filesize("yourfile.ext")); //from the first byte to the last truncate

//3 - File should be empty and still in writing mode.

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    fwrite($file, $array[$i]);
}
```

With `ftruncate` be aware of these issues regard the second param:

- If size is larger than the file then the file is extended with null bytes.
- If size is smaller than the file then the file is truncated to that size.
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php

Answer (score 0):

```
fopen($file, 'r+')
```

Includes reading and writing.  Go forth and prosper.

r+ description:
Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

w+ description: 
Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Either I don't understand your answer, or you didn't understand my question. `r+` ok, but won't clear the file before writing to it. `w+` good for clearing, but what good is reading an empty file?

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate lock empty file and call flock($file, LOCK_EX); on that file and open another file for writing.

Comment: Its possible to do this without the need of a 2nd file